# How to localize files in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

We add key/value pairs in AppResources for each language then easily use it in binding. But I have a long list of names of countries in a separate XML file for each language written in its own script.

Now, how can I use for french the french XML file and for english the english one?

(Answer to the coming question: "what have you tried or where is your code?", infact I'm at the beginning so no code, but I searched but didn't find any result, personally, sorry!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, why not just convert that XML file to a `rex` file and then use the standard localization APIs?

Failing that, you could add a localizable string to your application that is the file path to the XML file. That way, you use the standard `ResourceManager` to get the path and then handle it using your custom parsing.

Comment: thanks @Richard. but, size of the files will get about 15MB and I don't want to load all of them and use extra resources, Will the first way load all of them at once? the second way I guess will not, right?

Comment: Neither will load all of them until necessary. Have a look at [Localizing your app](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff637522%28v=vs.105%29.aspx#BKMK_LocalizingYourApplication) on MSDN and you'll see that each language has it's own `resx` file.