# Localization for Windows Phone8 application

Tags: localization, windows-phone-8

I want to provide **localization support** to **windows phone 8 application**.

In Application's Settings Page User will find two languages **English** and **Arabic**.

So when user clicks on any language, the application should display all the content in the corresponding language.

The selected language should not change the Phone's language means the language change should reflect in the application only.

I'm looking forward for your response.

Thanks & Regards

Suresh

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17288568/how-to-localize-files-in-windows-phone-8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all add resx file of arabic and then whenever you want to change the language then write
if you want to change to arabic

```
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("ar-AE");
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("ar-AE");
```

else write

```
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
```

I hope it will help ....

Comment: Hi Sandeep, I did as you said. Whenever i click on the Arabic language button then the title is not changing to arabic. I don't know what was the wrong.

Comment: you will have to bind the title with the property in resource file like 

Text="{Binding Path=LocalizedResources.Propertyname,Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}"
where property name will be the name of the property in resource file

Comment: Hi Sandeep, I have given like this <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path= LocalizedResources.ApplicationTitle, Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}}" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" Margin="12,0"/>. But still i'm not getting the arabic text in title.

Comment: you will have to reload that page means after changing language you will have to call that page again like navigationservices.navigate(new uri("pagename",urikind.relative));

Comment: Hi Sandeep, private void Ar_btn_Clicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("ar-SA");
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("ar-SA");
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
        }
now also there is no result.

Comment: have you checked your resources does it have different values for application title in both of them  because in default case they are both same so if they are same then try by changing it in arabic version ?

Comment: Yea I have checked. I have different values. I'm not getting arabic text. If you don't mind could you please give me your mail id. I'll send my code to your mail address so that you can easily check what was wrong in my code. I'm new to windows phone development. So please give me your mail id.